# How do I store file names that have spaces in a variable in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep, sh

Hi so I have a text file called MYFILES.txt

when I run grep --null ".txt" MYFILES.txt it displays the filenames with the space character correctly

```
grep --null ".txt" MYFILES.txt

my file 1.txt
my file 2.txt
my file 3.txt
my file 4.txt
```

However in the shell script if I have something like this then then space character is being excluded:
I need to store each file name I grep from the text in FILE variable with the space character included

```
for FILE in $( grep --null ".txt" MYFILES.txt)
do
   echo "${FILE}"
done

my
file
1.txt
my
file
2.txt
my
file
3.txt
my
file
4.txt
```

Comment: This is [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the filenames don't contain newlines

```
grep .txt MYFILES.txt | while IFS= read -r file ; do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Comment: To preserve leading/trailing whitespace in each line: `while IFS= read -r file; ...` -- that invocation will read each line exactly.